# Is it possible to set breakpoints in CoderPad for C#?

Tags: c#

Taking an interview within CoderPad for c# and wondering if we can set breakpoints for easy debugging. I looked at the Sandbox they provide and I don't see any obvious way to do it. Are we only left with Console statements or other mechanisms to output results, like to a text file, for reviewing what the code is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot set breakpoints in Coderpad. The only means of debugging I know is to print to console.